# For loop with and without curly braces in filter method works differently?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have this for loop in my code which works properly without curly braces(took me hours to figure out), in the function forTheScope, which doesn't work with curly braces.I want to know why?

```
function destroyer(arr) {
// Remove all the values
a=[];
for(var b=0; b<arguments.length; b++ ) {
a.push(arguments[b]);
}

function forTheScope(item) {
debugger;
for (var m = 1; m < a.length; m++) // this for loop works
  if (item == a[m]) // but when i put curly braces, it doesn't?
    return false;  //
return true; //
}

/*===== This is the for loop with braces =====
function forTheScope(item) {
debugger;
for (var m = 1; m < a.length; m++) {
  if (item == a[m]) {
   return false;  
  } else {
   return true;
  }
}
}
========== End of the loop ==========*/

return a[0].filter(function filterArray(item,index,array) {
return forTheScope(item);
});
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Comment: Post the version of the code that does not work; it depends on exactly *how* you added the `{ }`.

Comment: @Pointy please see my edit

Comment: OK, updating the answer.

Comment: I up-voted because placing someone in -1 is dickish because the question is not up to your standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
for (var m = 1; m < a.length; m++)
  if (item == a[m])
    return false;
return true;
```

is interpreted as exactly as if it were written like this:

```
for (var m = 1; m < a.length; m++) {
  if (item == a[m])
    return false;
}
return true;
```

A `for` loop header is syntactically followed by a single statement. That `if` statement, in turn, fills that requirement. However, wrapping the whole thing in `{ }` *also* creates a single "compound" statement.

Of course, if the `{ }` were added some other way, then things would be different.

*edit* — OK, now that you've updated the question to include the errant version, it's clear what the difference is. Your code is different in a particular and very significant way from the working version, and it really has nothing to do with `{ }`.  It's that `else` that's the problem:

```
for (var m = 1; m < a.length; m++) {
  if (item == a[m]) {
   return false;  
  } else {
   return true;
  }
}
```

You've moved the `return true` into the `else` clause, so now it's **inside** the loop instead of outside. In the working version, or in my version with `{ }` above, it's outside the loop and so won't happen until the loop is completely finished (unless the loop exits with `return false;` first).

In your version, the very first iteration of the loop will either exit the function with `return false;` or else it will exit with `return true;`. The loop will never get any further than that first iteration.

Comment: this is the code with braces i wanted to work                                     function forTheScope(item) {
debugger;
for (var m = 1; m < a.length; m++) {
  if (item == a[m]) {
   return false;  
  } else {
   return true;
  }
}
}

Comment: Reading your answer I realized my question is stupid, thanks a lot! I appreciate it

Comment: @learningjavascriptks no, don't feel bad. The only way to learn a programming language (or anything) is to experience mistakes.